# Should I also measure clCreateContext() when profiling OpenCL code?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

Recently I'm programming OpenCL code which handles some images.
After completing the code, I need to benchmark OpenCL code and native C(or C++) code which does same job.

My question arouses from above. Specifically which steps should I contain to time measuring?

Majority of books and questions on StackOverflow only measures time of executing clEnqueueNDRangeKernel() with using clGetEventProfilingInfo() and clWaitForEvents().

My senior said I need to contain buffer copying jobs(C memory to cl_mem) since native C code doesn't have such steps.
Then should I contain program creating & kernel building step, argument setting step, *.cl source code file reading step, and (most curious stuff)clCreateContext() step?

According to [[this paper]](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261272613_OpenCL_Performance_Evaluation_on_Modern_Multicore_CPUs?_sg=DkyC7Mn1Hr_TCnpBKNGkee_V090KgU2PmxcZjdfRT8wVSvMXm4S2OTm51hFvKy8Sgc8UmF4U7hkyvpLj6Mhv2g), clCreateContext() consumes largest time compared with other steps like below.
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUitT.jpg)

Android OpenCL code example from SONY also only gets elapsed time of clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(). Check here -> developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/code-example-module/opencl-code-example/

If above is right, is it right that I should only measure the very native C code which does same job in OpenCL kernel code?

Or are there various perspective to profiling and comparing OpenCL & native C code?

---

PLUS: My program is going to handle continuous image (like video) so there'll be frequent memory copy between GPU and other memory. Then I should also get time for copying memory in both OpenCL code and native C code, right?

Answer (score 1):

I mean, that obviously depends on what you need to measure.

Generally, if you care about the total run time of your program, measure the total runtime, *including* context creation.

In reality, you usually don't use openCL to do workloads that, over the whole life time of a program, take less time than the context creation. If that is the case, I'd be sure to check whether using openCL makes sense, at all. OpenCL is a single instruction, much much much data architecture. Hence, I think you might be constructing testbenches with simply too little work to be done to ever get statistically sufficient data.

For example, the timers you use to measure the time something takes to execute have some *granularity*, typically in the multiples of microseconds. If your workload takes shorter than let's say 500 µs, then what you're measuring is practically unusable as benchmark. This is a common problem for the performance comparison of many things!

Comment: Thank you for your advice :)